# how to add multiple column sum total in datatable

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have issue in showing sum total of some columns in data table. One issue is my table is dynamically created i.e user select columns to show so that column index are not fixed!

Secondly footerCallback on adding code throws ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTf' of undefined error

```
<tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'> <span style="float:right;"id ='totalcol1'></span> </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
```

FooterCAllback is defined inside var table=('#mytable').Datatable()

```
 "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
  var api = this.api(), data;
  $(api.column(11).footer()).html(
        api.column(11).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) { return a + b;})
     );
/* For second column
  $(api.column(12).footer()).append(
        api.column(12).data().reduce( function ( a, b ) { return a + b;})
     );*/
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an [example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html) that looks like exactly what you want to do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you I have tried this and my issue is the column index is dynamic ..I can't use 4 as show above, also If the some fields (salary,tax) are present only then the total row footer needs to get inserted in dynamic result.

Comment: About the index, you could use a variable instead of "4". So when you change the column index the code would fit the change (as long you update the variable value)

Comment: You could also hide the footer on your own if the columns (salary, tax) are not displayed

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I am trying